# How to insert data in oracle database using stored procedure in c#?

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a below table in my oracle database.
I wanat to insert these data using stored procedure and call it in my c# code.. 
can anyone help me on this?

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSFORMATION_LOG(    
    row_num number,
    source_file_path varchar(2000),
    transformed_file_path varchar(2000),
    transformed_status varchar(10),
    transformed_message varchar(1024),
    transformed_datetime TIMESTAMP    
)
```